# Is is possible to create generic computed properties with Self or associated type requirements in Swift, and if so how?

Tags: swift, generics, computed-properties

Consider the following:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: Equatable {}

// then, elsewhere...

var someValue: Any?

func setSomething<T>(_ value: T) where T: SomeProtocol {
    someValue = value
}

func getSomething<T>() -> T? where T: SomeProtocol {
    return someValue as? T
}
```

These functions work fine but essentially act like computed properties. Is there any way to implement something like the following?

```
var something<T>: T where T: SomeProtocol {
    get { return someValue as? T }
    set { someValue = newValue }
}
```

Thank you for reading. Apologies if this question has already been asked elsewhere, I have searched but sometimes my search fu is weak.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Where this comes handy?

Comment: Less code ergo greater clarity @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: Why computed property that returns stored property? Why not this: `struct SomeStruct<T:SomeProtocol> { var someValue: T? }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the computed property on a generic type, the computed property itself cannot define a generic type parameter.

```
struct Some<T:SomeProtocol> {
    var someValue:Any

    var something:T? {
        get {
            return someValue as? T
        }
        set {
            someValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ScottyBlades you can define `something` in an extension to `Some`, but you still need the generic struct/class. Only having `SomeProtocol` won't work.